# How to move company voip phones to a different subnet by modifying DHCP of a Cisco Switch?

Tags: cisco, dhcp, voip

Our company has replaced its old voip phones with new ones which are the NEC phones. We are done with the configuration part, and the phones are working fine. But I want the phones to be in a different subnet, so that my Server DHCP is not full. I have a cisco sg300 switch, and I want it to give the devices to a different ip subnet, and even have access to the internet via the phone. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like it should just be a matter of adding another DHCP scope which should be covered by the DHCP server's documentation. Are you using the sg300 as the DHCP server or is it relaying requests to another DHCP server?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to configure a new vlan just for the phone. On each interface, you should be able to set the '**switchport voice vlan**' command. On this new vlan, you can define a new DHCP pool and assign addresses to the phones.

We've used this with Cisco IP Phones with no problem, so you may want to test that your NEC IP phones work with the '**voice vlan**' command before rolling it out.